# 2.3 : Zero tax but tax amount is not subtracted from subtotal

Tags: magento2, tax

I have a Magento 2.3 store which operates for B2C and B2B so all prices are including VAT. For any company with a valid VAT inside of the EU the tax-rate should be set to 0%.

For tax calculations we use the Geissweb module which handles the VAT number validation.

What happens now is that if the subtotal (incl tax) is 500 and the taxrate is 0%, the grand total also will be 500 for a non-domestic company with a valid VAT number, while it should be 413.22

anyone have a clue how this happens ?

[image: this is what happens]

Answer (score 0):

In magento admin :

Admin > Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings = Reset all to system defaults